# Custom counter for cross-referencing is incorrect when used inside tabularray

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, tabularray

I would like share with something. I have created a custom counter to cross-reference sub figures.

For some reason, the counter is wrong if I use it inside `tblr` environment (the one defined in `tabularray` package). I tested similar approach with `tabular` and the latter works as expected.

I am still on TexLive 2021 with the most recent updates:

```
Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021)  (format=lualatex 2022.3.25)  25 MAR 2022 13:25
Package: tabularray 2022-03-01 v2022A Typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
Package: cleveref 2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
```

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{mycustomcounter}
\renewcommand\themycustomcounter{(\alph{mycustomcounter})}
\crefname{mycustomcounter}{subfigure}{subfigures}
\Crefname{mycustomcounter}{Subfigure}{Subfigures}
\crefformat{mycustomcounter}{#2subfigure~#1#3}
\Crefformat{mycustomcounter}{#2Subfigure~#1#3}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setcounter{mycustomcounter}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=0.9\textwidth,
        colspec={X[c] X[c]},
    }
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \\
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example1}
        \themycustomcounter
        &
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example2}
        \themycustomcounter
    \end{tblr}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setcounter{mycustomcounter}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \\
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example3}
        \themycustomcounter
        &
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example4}
        \themycustomcounter
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

References to subfigures: \labelcref{fig:example1}, \labelcref{fig:example2}, \labelcref{fig:example3}, \labelcref{fig:example4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce, but I can't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why, but this is documented behavior. The manual says "You need to load counter library with `\UseTblrLibrary{counter}`, if you want to modify some LaTeX counters inside `tabularray` tables." And indeed, with it, it works as expected.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{mycustomcounter}
\renewcommand\themycustomcounter{(\alph{mycustomcounter})}
\crefname{mycustomcounter}{subfigure}{subfigures}
\Crefname{mycustomcounter}{Subfigure}{Subfigures}
\crefformat{mycustomcounter}{#2subfigure~#1#3}
\Crefformat{mycustomcounter}{#2Subfigure~#1#3}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \setcounter{mycustomcounter}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=0.9\textwidth,
        colspec={X[c] X[c]},
    }
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \\
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example1}
        \themycustomcounter
        &
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example2}
        \themycustomcounter
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \setcounter{mycustomcounter}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        &
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \\
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example3}
        \themycustomcounter
        &
        \refstepcounter{mycustomcounter}
        \label{fig:example4}
        \themycustomcounter
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


References to subfigures: \labelcref{fig:example1}, \labelcref{fig:example2}, \labelcref{fig:example3}, \labelcref{fig:example4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I am glad it can work and sorry I missed that in the first place. I was reading through the manual at some point but never sport such thing.

Comment: @Celdor Oh, I didn't mean to be critical, I didn't know it either and have just found out about it. It's just that it's all I know... ;-)

Comment: tabularray processes a tabular more than once, and so counter need special treatment, e.g. https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/89

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, that explains it! I'm yet to get acquainted with `tabularray`, it is in my "to do someday" list. :)